# SQLite if input exists in the database skip or overwrite the existing

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a question for my assignment. I have a database with sqlite in my android app and the location updates come and writes to the sql db, but there is some same data with the coming updates. I want to check if there is same location in my db, the system skips or overwrites the existing location info in db as x,y I have some code I post it below but my code always adds or always overwrites if I change it as Update Replace or something like that also I have the id in my databases.

How to change and organize my code for the job?

```
public void DBCreate(){
    SQLITEDATABASE = openOrCreateDatabase("LatLongDatabase3", Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable74(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, FAVCurrentLocationLAT VARCHAR,FAVCurrentLocationLONG VARCHAR);");
}

public void SubmitData2SQLiteDB(){
    SQLiteQuery = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable74(id, FAVCurrentLocationLAT, FAVCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES(NULL,'"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');";
    SQLITEDATABASE.execSQL(SQLiteQuery);
    Toast.makeText(CampaignActivity.this,"OK", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use `INSERT OR REPLACE` like you should.
What `INSERT OR REPLACE` or simply `REPLACE` does is:
Checks before inserting a new row if that row would violate a constraint and
-if **it does violate a constraint**, it deletes the existing row and then inserts the new row
-if **it does not violate a constraint**, then goes on and inserts the new row
In your table the only existing constraint is:

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

and nothing else. 
This means that anytime you try to insert a new row:
-If the new `id` **already exists** in the table then this existing row will be deleted and the new row will be inserted
-If the new `id` **does not already exist** then the new row will be inserted.
Is this what you want?
I think what you want is a constraint on the uniqueness of the 2 columns `(FAVCurrentLocationLAT,FAVCurrentLocationLONG)` which should be the `PRIMARY KEY` in the table, as I don't think that `id` is needed (or maybe it is needed but it is not the reason for an insert to fail).
So change the `CREATE` statement of the table to this:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable74 (
  FAVCurrentLocationLAT TEXT, 
  FAVCurrentLocationLONG TEXT, 
  PRIMARY KEY(FAVCurrentLocationLAT,FAVCurrentLocationLONG)
);
```

Now every time you execute the statement:

```
SQLiteQuery = 
  "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable74(FAVCurrentLocationLAT, FAVCurrentLocationLONG) " +
  "VALUES('"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"');";
```

new pairs of values will be inserted and existing will be replaced.
The replacement of course is not needed, so you could just check by code if the values already exist in the table and if they do simply don't execute an `INSERT` (instead of `REPLACE`) statement.

Comment: Sir thank you for your response, Yes ! you are right it seems like a good solution I am trying now, do I have to name them text because I have to make some calculations after they have written on the db.

Comment: The reason I have TEXT in the statement is because your code has `VARCHAR`. You can replace it with `INTEGER` or `REAL` if the values contain decimal places.

Comment: Sir values are double like that 40.12345 which  can I use

Comment: Then use `REAL`.

Comment: Sir I use varchar and it works amazing :) I am very Happy about that thank you so much I have understood the technic. Can I use it for another db like user id = "campaign in starbucs" like text

Comment: In reality for SQLite everything is TEXT. So you can store anything in a column defined as TEXT or INTEGER. So you can use TEXT. The data type VARCHAR is not SQLite specific. It will be treated as TEXT.

Comment: Thank you sir you saved my day :)

Comment: Sir I just have one more question I tried to do same for my other db method but have some errors I posted in answers could you please help me if you have time

Comment: In the CREATE statement don't use REAL, this is for numbers. Use TEXT. And in the INSERT statement delete all REAL. Also delete that question/answer you posted.

Comment: Sir I deleted my old question.

Comment: `INSERT OR REPLACE INTO myTable2(FAVCampaignName, FAVCampaigncampaignStartDate, FAVCampaigncampaignEndDate)" + " VALUES('"+FSname+"','"+FScampaignStartDate+"','"+FScampaignEndDate+"');`

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myTable2(FAVCampaignName TEXT,FAVCampaigncampaignStartDate TEXT, FAVCampaigncampaignEndDate TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (FAVCampaignName,FAVCampaigncampaignStartDate, FAVCampaigncampaignEndDate));`

Comment: Sir I have done it. I feel bad because it was a minor dismissing :( Thank you so much again and again. God bless you.

Comment: Fine if it worked. Also delete your new question as it is no longer of any use.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO myTable74(id, FAVCurrentLocationLAT, FAVCurrentLocationLONG) 
VALUES(NULL,'"+mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()+"','"+mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()+"')
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM myTable74 WHERE id = your_id);
```

But `Insert or Replace` and `IF not exists` do not go together, you cannot replace something which doesn't exist. So above is just `Insert`

And of course you can change `id` by which ever column you want to check whether it exists

Comment: Thank you sir, what do I have to write to "your_id", Can I copy the code and use it lite this does the code automatically do the job for every update

Comment: Replace it with your `id`. Do you want to check whether item in db exist by id, or latitude or longitude?

Comment: Sir I did not understand how can I change the id. If lat or long exists,it can change the lat long variables.

Comment: I mean in `(SELECT id FROM myTable74 WHERE id = your_id)` query you can change `id` by which ever column you want, `your_id` is just a placeholder, enter real value there

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Replace is that if a record exists, it will delete that record, along with its primary key value, and then insert a new record with a new primary key value.  If you have other tables that reference that old primary key value that could be a problem.  What you really want to do is check to see if the values for a particular lat/lon are already in the database, and if so, leave them alone (don't delete then re-insert).  But if not, then just do a plain insert.  So, taking the lead of a previous post, I would modify it slightly as so:

```
// Don't include ID in the INSERT as primary key should be auto-incrementing field
INSERT INTO myTable74(FAVCurrentLocationLAT, FAVCurrentLocationLONG) VALUES(mCurrentLocation.getLatitude(), mCurrentLocation.getLongitude())
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT id FROM myTable74 WHERE FAVCurrentLocationLAT = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude() AND FAVCurrentLocationLONG= mCurrentLocation.getLongitude());
```